# htaccess rewrite gives LimitInternalRecursion error

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a .htaccess file with the following code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

But when I visit my site I get this error

```
[client 127.0.0.1] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

The LogLevel debug doesn't give me a backtrace and I don't think increasing the Limit on internal recursion is wise.

Does anyone have experience with this type of error?

Comment: With what URL are you testing this? Can you enable rewritelog? That should give you your answer. Also, if possible, try to put the rewriterules in your config, not in .htaccess

Comment: This means you have a loop in your redirect rules, `Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.`, please post such a backtrace ...

Comment: I'm testing with a domain name http://laravel.dev/ wich would automatically redirect to laravel.dev/index.php but the htaccess from laravel is not working on my server

Comment: I have LogLevel set to debug but I don't see any log with a backtrace.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that the request is for `/index.html`.

Your first rewrite condition says "if the URL requested is not a directory, rewrite it with a redirect to itself with an added slash." So the URL will be rewritten with a redirect to `/index.html/`. Which will again be rewritten with an added slash, etc ad infinitum. This is why you get the error message.

Comment: hmm this is literally the htaccess laravel 4 uses, which must work. I don't get why it's not working on my server. https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/develop/public/.htaccess

Answer (score 2):

In case future folks stumble across this...

I had a similar problem, where my Laravel 5.1 project was giving 500 errors on the browser and `Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error` in the logfile.

I was able to solve it by adding `RewriteBase /` just after `RewriteEngine On` in my `.htaccess` file.

Hopefully this can help someone.